# Does the Mandelbrot set have dense interior?

Tags: complex-dynamics, mandelbrot-set

Let $M$ be the Mandelbrot set.

**Question:** Is the interior of $M$ dense in $M$?

My intuition is that this is true, and moreover that hyperbolic components of the interior are dense in $M$ as well, and moreover that this is known (as it is not very close to the Hyperbolicity Conjecture and thus not too hard).  Is that right?

Comment: Have you tried sending this question via e-mail to John Hubbard?  I suspect the answer is yes, and John would know where a proof is published.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is positive and this is not difficult (a normal families argument). The boundary
of the Mandelbrot set is the set of $J$-instability. Every point $c_0$ of this set is a limit of $c_n$ such that $z\mapsto z^2+c_n$ has a superattracting cycle. So actually hyperbolic components accumulate
to every boundary point of $M$.

(MLC is related to a much harder statement, Fatou conjecture, that interior of $M$ consists of only hyperbolic components).

Refs: M. Lyubich, Some typical properties of the dynamics of rational mappings, English transl.: Russian Math surveys,
38, 1983, or

M. Lyubich, The dynamics of rational transforms: the topological picture,
Russ. Math. Surv. 41, No. 4, 43-117 (1986);

Comment: What does MLC mean in your answer?

Comment: Mandelbrot local connectedness, I believe

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95701/the-deep-significance-of-the-question-of-the-mandelbrot-sets-local-connectednes/105524#105524

Comment: Indeed, I suppose it is further true that attraction points of hyperbolic components are dense on the boundary.